What was sita's fault?
In Valmiki Ramayana Yuddhakhanda chapter 115 we see Rama rebuking Sita because of suspicion regarding Sita's chastity. My question is even if Ravana forcefully slept with Sita {I know that was not the case} then what was Sita's fault? What could she have done to stop it? Why couldn't Rama just accept her?

Rama is mostly presented as a human and is never aware that he is God.  He reacted as any human would have reacted under those circumstances.  @titaniumww7

thanks for posting your doubt. Recently I myself got this doubt cleared. So basically if we see translations of those slokas we might get different idea of things, to get real meaning of these things you should try to know the whole story or at least 10 slokas before or after that sloka. It really makes the story clearer.
So in previous slokas, Ram asks Vibhishan to bring Sita adorned like a queen in chariot. And when he brings her, then Ram says such harsh words to her that I did all this battle just to protect the name of his lineage and not for her, he even goes on to say that you (sita) are now free to go and live with anyone, I don't care. Lakshaman gets very angry as to see why his Brother is saying like that. Sita ji starts crying there and asks Lakshman to start a fire into which she would jump to sacrifice her life (one misconception here is that Ram asks her to give Agni pariksha, but as per Valmiki Ramayan, Sita herself says that she'll jump into fire). Lakshman couldn't understand this whole scenario and just about to talk to his brother and then Ram gives him a hint that do as what is told to you {the word used is 'ishara karna' in hindi, then Lakshman ji understands that Ram knows what he's doing and let the situation unfold}. After that when Sita ji is about to jump, Agni appears and Lords appear to give evidence of purity of Sita's heart. Then Ram tells that I knew this already. Here he just wanted the audience and general people to themselves accept this fact of purity of Sita Maa, because we know any kind of rumour can spread among people quickly, so to save false allegations against her Ram did that.
You should consult some scholars or good resources only to read texts and get to know their meanings. One good resource that I found is '21 Notes' channel on YouTube for reference to Valmiki Ramayan. There's also this great podcast of Yashodeep Deodar on Hyperquest channel regarding some myths about Valmiki Ramayan.
